# Best way to fix stairs that are starting to seperate

Tags: repair, stairs

Our main staircase is a series of two-piece wooden steps comprised of a large plank and a small edge attached to it. The main planks seem fine but about half of the edges are starting to pull away the planks. It is especially noticeable if you make the mistake of putting most of your weight on the edge as it will flex out about a half inch.

What is the best way to go about fixing this? My current plan is to pry off the edge pieces and re-glue/nail them back in place assuming I don't find any damage to what's underneath.

[Pictures of the steps in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM9mW.jpg)

Comment: Wood dowels/biscuits plus glue might be stronger.

Comment: The step supports might not be as flat as possible, aiding to the separation, unless the ones using the steps tend to use(put their weight on) the rounded edge more than the flat step.